# How to select records where a column is equal to a parameter that can be null in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, where-clause

I have this table

```
create table [test]
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    name nvarchar(50),
    clientid int null -- Can be null
)
```

I have this stored procedure:

```
create procedure sp_GetValue
    (@client int = null)
begin
    select * 
    from test 
    where clientid = @client
end
```

Problem is when client is equal to null it returns nothing even though I have records with null clientid

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Boolean logic :

```
where (@client is null and clientid is null) or clientid = @client
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `or`:

```
select *
from test
where clientid = @client or (clientid is null and @client is null);
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have a `NULL` safe equality operator (the standard is `is not distinct from`).

Also, the `OR` might have an impact on index usage.  You can include `option (recompile)` which should fix that problem.

Comment: the or doesn't cause a problem here. SQL Server recognizes this pattern as a simple equality [with `IS` semantics rather than `EQ` semantics](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/06/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.html)

Answer (score 1):

You want null-safe comparison. Unlike some other databases, SQL Server does not have a specific operator for this, so you are left with some logic to describe the possible cases:

```
select * 
from test 
where (clientid is null and @client is null) or clientid = @client
```